# Why are tables segmented when exporting to parquet from AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds, parquet

We use Python's boto3 library to execute [`start_export_task`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.start_export_task) to trigger a RDS snapshot export (to S3). This successfully generates a directory in S3 that has a predicable, [expected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html) structure. Traversing down through that directory to any particular table directory (as in export_identifier/database_name/schema_name.table_name/) I see several `.parquet` files.
[image]
I download several of these files and convert them to pandas dataframes so I can look at them. They are all structured the same and seem to clearly be pieces of the same table. But they range in size from 100KB to 8MB in seemingly unpredictable size segments. Do these files/'pieces' of the table account for all its rows? Do they repeat/overlap at all? Why are they segmented so (seemingly) randomly? What parameters control this segmenting?

Ultimately I'm looking for documentation on this part of parquet folder/file structure. I've found plenty of information on how [individual files are structured](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/all-you-need-know-parquet-file-structure-depth-rohan-karanjawala) and [partitioning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery). But I think this falls slightly outside of those topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to like this, but from AWS' perspective this is an implementation detail and according to the docs:

> The file naming convention is subject to change. Therefore, when reading target tables we recommend that you read everything inside the base prefix for the table.
>
> — [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.FileNames)

Most of the tools that work with Parquet don't really care about the number or file names of the parquet files. You just point something like Spark or Athena to the prefix of the table and it will read all the files and figure out how they fit together.

In the API there are also no parameters to influence this behavior. If you prefer a single file for aesthetic reasons or others, you could use something like a Glue Job to read the table prefixes, coalesce the data per table in a single file and write it to S3.

Comment: Thanks. I can live with that. This gives me the reassurance that I just need to load all the files. I'll play to my strengths and load from pandas.read_parquet() and then concat the dataframes. But I still don't know the reasoning behind segmenting the files in seemingly unpredictable, inconsistent sizes.